# Uwc3ng cs server and mariadb mysql issue

Tags: mariadb

I get this in my server and i dont know how to fix it

> L 01/30/2024 - 13:20:49: [uwc3ng.amxx] [MYSQLX] Error in querying database, location: 1
> L 01/30/2024 - 13:20:49: [uwc3ng.amxx] [MYSQLX] Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 1 (1064)
> L 01/30/2024 - 13:20:49: [uwc3ng.amxx] [MYSQLX] Query statement: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS uwc3ng_player ( player_id int(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, player_steamid varchar(25) NOT NULL default '', player_ip varchar(20) NOT NULL default '', player_name varchar(35) NOT NULL default '', player_xp int(16) default NULL, PRIMARY KEY  (player_id), KEY `player_nam

Please help

I tryed searching on google with
Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 1 (1064)

and

Query statement: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS uwc3ng_player ( player_id int(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, player_steamid varchar(25) NOT NULL default '', player_ip varchar(20) NOT NULL default '', player_name varchar(35) NOT NULL default '', player_xp int(16) default NULL, PRIMARY KEY  (player_id), KEY `player_nam

thou i could not understand how to fix the issue

Comment: Hint, the manual for create table that the message is referring to is [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/). Second, why are you creating MyISAM tables?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a CREATE TABLE syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS uwc3ng_player ( 
player_id int(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
player_steamid varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
...
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

wheras the engine should be defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS uwc3ng_player ( 
player_id int(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
player_steamid varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
...
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

There is no reason to use MyISAM tables. Use InnoDB instead.

Comment: it is not me that done the script its the one that made uwc3ng mod for cs
i am totally unaware of how to do this sense im a windows user and this is in linux now
so InnoDB instead of Myisam will fix the issue ?

Comment: Based on the error, the problem is in definition "TYPE" vs "ENGINE". The MyISAM vs InnoDB is just a sidenote.